# How to replace foreign key by its associated value in django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, fetch, django-queryset

I'm fairly new to django and i would need your help!

I wrote an api/route view that query the database and return a JSON to my fetch function in my javascript.

Is there a way to query the database and got back a queryset with foreign key replaced by its associated value ?

I though i could use `ModelName.objects.select_related( 'field ')` but i didn't understand how it works.
If you have a solution or advices on better way to achieve the goal, Thanks in advance!

Context in pseudo-code:

// HTML //

- Button onclick function get_list_of_data

// JS //

function get_list_of_data:

- Fetch URL of route django
- Convert response to JSON
- iterating through JSON to fill HTLM div

// Django //

- use ModelName.objects.filter( name = name ) to get list of data in Queryset
- use serializers.serialize(json, ...") to get JSON from Queryset
- return JsonResponse (json_query)

Comment: yes you can pass your object id in js data, then get it in your backend(django) and then make what ever you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem well, when you serialize a model that has a `ForeignKey` field defined you get only the `id` value in JSON response but you would like to get the whole object (not only a number) returned.
The way to do that is to specifically write serializer for that `ForeignKey` model and then use it within the serializer od the model that you are trying to fetch.
You haven't provided any code, but here is some example that might help you:

```
class SecondModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
        fields = '__all__'


class FirstModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foreign_key_field = SecondModelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel
        fields = ('id', 'foreign_key_field', 'field1', 'field2')
```

Here in your `FirstModelSerializer` you specifically told Django to use `SecondModelSerializer` for your `ForeignKey` field (I named it `foreign_key_field`). This way Django will know how to serialize that field instead of returning only the `id` value.